# Iterating through a file and removing reserved words

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file that I need to read and find any reserved keywords that are used as identifiers. If a reserved keyword is found as an identifier. I need to add res_keyword. I've made a list of the reserved words:

`keywords =['cos','abs', 'sin','begin','end','input','output']` 
So, if in the file, I encounter:
`input cos;` I need to change it to `input res_cos;`
This is what I have so far:

```
keywords =['cos','abs', 'sin','begin','end','input','output']
with open('filename', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
for i in keywords:
    if i == data:
        data = data.replace(keywords, 'res')
with open('filename', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Edit: Here's a snippet of the input file:

```
input cos;
cos = x + y
```

cos would need to be changed to `res_cos`

Comment: `data` is the entire file content; it will never equal `i`.

Comment: Could you include an example input file for this question.

Comment: @Robson, I added a snippet

Comment: @AronChabane Great, although that isn't really enough to infer much from. Presumably you have loads of ways that these keywords could be used. For example, they could be used as function names, calls to a function, variable names, assignment to a variable, etc. Many ways. Determining when a word is being used as a name and not as the language feature is going to be a massive and difficult task, because you'll need to parse the code and figure out every situation. I think it would be better to look at alternative solutions for this. Why do you need to do this task? How many files are there?

Comment: You should use a regexp for this, so you can match *whole words*. Try something like this: `data = re.sub(rf'\b({"|".join(keywords)})\b', r'res_\1', data)`.

Comment: @AronChabane If both "input" and "cos" are keywords, then surely "input cos" would change to "res_input res_cos"?

Comment: @ekhumoro, That's what I was thinking too, and I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: @AronChabane Why is "input" a keyword if you don't want to replace it? You really need to show a much larger example input file and show what the expected output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but if I am not mistaken what I noticed is
You are doing this.

```py
data = data.replace(keywords, 'res')
```

You are using `keywords` list in the replace method, but what you should do is something like this

```py
data = data.replace(i, 'res_' + i)
```

However, this works if the file `data` was a single string. When you do this

```py
if i == data:
```

you are treating `data` as a single string, and this will never evaluate to true unless `data` is a single word.

Comment: This will change non-reserved words like `send` to `sres_end`.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes you are right, IDK how I could miss something like that. Going with RegEx is a better option I guess.